# This error occur when I call Sign function

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I am trying to sign up with google .But error message shows :
1.dispatch isn't a function (error message occur in sign in function)
2.A boolean is being passed as a fourth parameter to window.open . This is not used and may cause an exception in a future release.

Login.js:

```
     const { dispatch } = useContext(DispatchContext);
const Sign = () => {
auth
  .signInWithPopup(provider)
  .then((result) => dispatch({ type: "auth", payload: result.user }))
  .catch((err) => console.log(err.message));
```

};

context.js

```
    const [states, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, {
value: "",
input: "",
user: "",
```

});

Passing value

```
<DispatchContext.Provider value={dispatch}>

        {children}
   
</DispatchContext.Provider>
```

App.js

```
 const { user } = useContext(UserContext);
```

user doest contain anything.

Comment: There is a similar bug reported on [Github](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/4988)

Comment: There is nothing answer of it.

Answer (score 0):

Try downgrading to an earlier version, the latest v9 at the current time has a bug regarding an incorrect parameter being passed resulting in `window.location` error.